# How to temporarily apply (or archive) PATCH/DIFF changes from Tortoise SVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, diff, patch, visualsvn

I've been using **Tortoise SVN + Visual SVN** for about a year since left the corporate world to do my own startup. There's one feature in Tortoise SVN that I've never figured out:

How can I **bundle up** a bunch of **changes** into a PATCH or DIFF file and either: A) share them with my co-founder; or B) archive them into a standalone change that I can either "apply" or "revert" on my dev box?

At my previous employer, we used an internal tool that let us build so-called **DPK files** that contained a set of local changes. You could add changed files to the DPK and then share it with colleagues. They could either review the changes in a Diff tool or apply all the changes from the DPK to test your change on their box.  After the review was complete, you could then check in these changes.  You could also have multiple DPK's applied at the same time (provided you didn't have overlapping changes).

I want to achieve the same thing with Tortoise SVN + Visual SVN in the VS2010 IDE.

My real-world scenario is that I have some extensive change pending but uncompleted on my box. I want to ZIP up these changes and **store** them in a DIFF file, **revert** the changes, move on to something else, work on that, and in a few days **reapply** my changes from the archived DIFF file.

Comment: Oh, come on man. That's a totally off-the-wall answer and a waste of time. Clearly, I'm not going to abandon SVN just because of this issue. I can understand levity on a casual forum, but this is not an appropriate answer on a forum like StackOverflow.

Comment: Its not an answer. Thats why I posted it as a comment. And honestly what you are doing is a great advantage that DVCS's have over SVN so... Git for example can automatically send emails with patches. And you could use branching for a lot of this.

Comment: Fair enough, but even a comment such as this is more "noise" than "signal". Anyway, in the absence of a real solution, I'll just XCOPY the changed files into a directory and then do a manual diff a few days from now, bring over the old changes inside BeyondCompare. That'll work, but it's so 20th century.

Comment: Just because you disagree that SVN is a source of problems doesn't make my comment noise. Its perfectly legitimate to switch to a more modern approach.

Comment: But I didn't ask "Please recommend an alternative source control platform." I asked how I can find a solution using Tortoise SVN + Visual SVN in the VS2010 IDE.  This exchange reminds me of something I see all the time on music forums like Harmony-Central.com. I guy makes a post stating, "I can't decide between this red and blue Stratocaster. Help me pick the right color." And then some guy comes in and says: "Strats suck! You should buy a Gretsch instead."

Comment: Comments are often used on this site to provide alternate solutions that may be used as an alternative to the question. This is _not an answer_. For example, you mention you are starting a business. Why not start with a DVCS instead of SVN? Usually the switch is somewhat painful halfway through...

Comment: Again, fair enough. However, in the context of what I'm trying to accomplish today, switching to GIT (or anything else) is not a solution. I'll admit that if Tortoise SVN doesn't support something like this, then it could be a long-term deal breaker for me. To be honest, I selected Visual SVN because of its elegant integration with Visual Studio. If GIT or something else offers the same level of VS2010 integration, then I will consider switching. But that doesn't help me with my immediate issue. And I'm still not convinced that what I'm trying to do is NOT possible w/ Tortoise SVN.

Comment: So, this is totally do-able in Tortoise SVN. After making the PATCH file, the trick is to apply the patch from the right location from within the working copy.  Here's some info: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html

Comment: Tried to do this, but I'm 4 points short of the century mark which is a requirement for answering your own question in under 8 hours. Thanks for the back-and-forth, mathepic. I will keep in mind other solutions, but at least I have something that works right now.  Just curious: what is the best DVCS-based solution that integrates with Visual Studio 2010? I'm looking for *deep* & seamless integration. If something like that is available, I'll give it an honest shake.

Comment: I would have to go with Mercurial, despite never using it, because Git is focused more on the unix side (although it works in windows, its not a primary target). I hear it has quite good VS integration but I've never used it (seeing as I don't really use VS itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reluctantly answering my own question. This feature is available with Tortoise SVN.  Basically, you make a PATCH file, distribute it or archive it, and then you apply the PATCH.  The only trick is to make sure you're in the right location in the WC (Working Copy) when you do the "apply".  When you apply, you'll get a popup menu to the left with a list of all files in the changelist. You can apply the patches one by one or in bulk.  Seems to work great. I should have drilled into the docs more before posting this question.

Here's the text for picking the location:

> "Patch files are applied to your
>   working copy. This should be done from
>   the same folder level as was used to
>   create the patch. If you are not sure
>   what this is, just look at the first
>   line of the patch file. For example,
>   if the first file being worked on was
>   doc/source/english/chapter1.xml and
>   the first line in the patch file is
>   Index: english/chapter1.xml then you
>   need to apply the patch to the
>   doc/source/ folder. However, provided
>   you are in the correct working copy,
>   if you pick the wrong folder level,
>   TortoiseSVN will notice and suggest
>   the correct level."

Be sure to pick the location carefully. If Tortoise SVN can't find it because you selected the wrong node in the VS file explorer, it will try to find a matching location and that might be wrong. In my tests, the Patch feature actually tried to map to a branch (!!) when I specified the wrong location.

Here's the relevant link:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html